# Spreadsheet mapping keys to tables

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Is it possible in Google Sheets or Excel to map a key to a table? For instance, `vlookup(A1, someTable, 2)` returns `{{1;2;3},{4;5;6}}`, where the cell `A1` is mapped to the table `{{1;2;...}}`

This is the equivalent to Python's:

```py
some_dict = {
    1: {11, 111, 1111},
    2: {22, 222, 2222},
    3: {33, 333, 3333}
}
```

More background: I have a list of math sequences. It would be convenient to access them through indices.

## What I Tried

In this example sheet:
[image: example]

I tried

```js
=hlookup(1, A:C, 2) // Expected output: {{1;2;3;4}, {1;1;2;3}}
```

But it seems like the `lookup` functions do not handle expanded arrays.

Comment: I think possible but we can't understand your question. Can you simply show sample data then expected output? Explain in brief to gain that output.

Comment: @Harun24HR I provided the expected output and how to gain it.

Comment: Cannot see which column is ` A:C` from the screenshot... Any sample file (with the said array)?

Comment: @p._phidot_ `A:C` is all the table that contains the numbers and arrays. Usually in `lookup` functions, the size of the table does not matter.

Comment: What I mean is.. in which cell the `={{1;2;3;4},{1;1;2;3}}`,`={{1;2;3;4},{1;4;9;16}}` and the `1` ,`2`,`3`  is located in sheet/A:C column... I couldn't really get/test how the  `=hlookup(1, A:C, 2)` works.